# help access 2007 sql tables?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

does anyone know where on access 2007 a function where i can access my sql database? i need it to create reports. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an ODBC connection.  In Microsoft Access, go to the File menu and select Get External Data and choose Link Tables... from the resulting menu.

Answer (score 1):

As well as with linked tables as suggested by ocdecio, you could also do an "Access Database Project" - which is basically an Access front end to a SQL back end.  If you did it this way, you could use all of your existing views, stored procs, functions, etc.

Comment: -1 -- Bad point, because you can't convert an existing MDB into an ADP. And ADPs are being deprecated by MS in favor of MDB + ODBC.

Comment: David - the question said nothing of converting an existing application to an ADP.  If you're going to downvote this one - at least provide a link to the source of your data so that we can all learn something from it.

Comment: I am no fan of the ADP format, but, FTR, form and report objects can be imported from an MDB to an ADP and from an ADP to an MDB with the caveat that it's pretty much just the layout that you're grabbing. Swapping the data bits out from one format to the other can be a huge headache.